# hibernate console configuration disappeared in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I'm working with Eclipse Indigo and the Hibernate tools/plugins (3.4.0...) by JBoss Red Hat. For the purpose of reverse engineering of Hibernate value object classes I created several console configurations with the wizard that pops up when clicking on add in the Hibernate Configurations view.

Later when I wanted to regenerate the classes, some of the configurations had dissapeared. When I wanted to add a new configuration with the name of one of the now dissapeared configurations the wizard tells me that the configuration already exists.

Since I couldn't find out where these configurations are stored I'm unable to do anything about it.

Do I have to create a new configuration with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and finally I found the file in this directory:

```
.\WORK-SPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches\miConsoleConfig.launch
```

But is better to edit from eclipse. The console configuration is only visible in Hibernate perspective under tab **Hibernate Configurations** next to the package explorer.